# html link: hide href from user

Tags: html, security

In an HTML file that is sent to someone by e-mail, is it possible to prevent the receiver from inspecting the href of a link in that HTML file?

I need to prevent the user from seeing/copying the url.

Comment: What kind of data you want to hide from the user? The entire address of site being visted or some particular parameters?

Comment: If you are able to hide it, what prevents them from seeing the url after they click the link?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It is entirely impossible.

The email client and the browser are both entirely under the control of the user (so you can't give them a URL without also giving it to the user).

Tricks might obfuscate the URL, but decoding it is trivial.

Comment: Wait, why not using inline JavaScript?

Comment: JS is client-based, it can at most obfuscate the address

Comment: @PraveenKumar — Because the user can extract the URL from the JavaScript and find out the URL.